# Python script that generate an HTML page

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm programming a simple python script that if launched on localhost (with apache) it will generate an html page.

My script is this (test.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cgitb                                
cgitb.enable()

import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

x="hello"
y="world"

f= open('my.html', 'r').read()
print f.format(x=val1, y=val2)
```

This opens an html page that has a simple Javascript in the head element:

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test html</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#select1").change(function() {
                    var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                    $("#select2 option").removeAttr("disabled").removeAttr("selected");
                    $("#select2 option").each(function() {
                        if($(this).val() != selectedVal && $(this).val() != -1)
                            $(this).attr("disabled","disabled").removeAttr("selected"); 
                    });
                });
            });
     </script>


    </head>
```

With a lot of code in the body. 
When I run the test.py it says: 
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

```
 /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/test.py in ()
    181 
    182 
    184 f= open('my.html', 'r').read()
=>  185 print f.format(x=val1, y=val2)
f = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN...\n </form>\n <hr>\n </body>\n</html>', f.format = <built-in method format of str object>, val1 = 0, val2 = '','
<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: '\n\t\t\t $("#select1")' 
      args = ('\n\t\t\t $("#select1")',) 
      message = '\n\t\t\t $("#select1")'
```

But if i delete the Javascript the python generates the html without problems, but i need that script.

How can i execute the script without error?

Comment: What do you think `f.format(x=val1, y=val2)` does?

Comment: it assign the string "x" at the input box "val1". The same for y and val2. The val1 and val2 are declared in the HTML body! It's only a test, but how can i execute the javascript?

Comment: Make sure that the Javascript doesn't look like a broken format string, as the error is telling you.  Also, you have an XSS hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that format expects anything between two French braces to be replaced by one of your format strings.  In your case, then, it tries to lookup

```
 $("#select1").change(function() {
                var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                $("#select2 option").removeAttr("disabled").removeAttr("selected");
                $("#select2 option").each(function() {
                    if($(this).val() != selectedVal && $(this).val() != -1)
                        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled").removeAttr("selected");
```

as a key in the kwargs you passed.  The solution, outlined here [String format a JSON string gives KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356810/string-format-a-json-string-gives-keyerror) is to use double braces.  Your new html file then should look something like this:

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test html</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {{
            $("#select1").change(function() {{
                var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                $("#select2 option").removeAttr("disabled").removeAttr("selected");
                $("#select2 option").each(function() {{
                    if($(this).val() != selectedVal && $(this).val() != -1)
                        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled").removeAttr("selected"); 
                }});
            }});
        }});
 </script>


</head>
```

(Note the changes from '{' to '{{' and '}' to '}}'.)

Let me know if you have any follow up questions/something didn't work.